# Swift3: Empty fetch when accessing Core Data from Watch Extension via AppGroups

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, watchos-3, appgroups

currently I'm working on an update for an already existing App (migration to Swift 3). I'm having targets for Today-, Search-, Message- and Watch Extensions. Every target needs to access the Core Data Model of my App, so I created an AppGroup and enabled the Capability for every target. Although I've subclassed the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, so everything is stored in a shared folder:

```
import CoreData
class PFPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
    override open class func defaultDirectoryURL() -> URL {
        if let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "add-groupname-here") {
            return url
        }
        // Fallback
        return super.defaultDirectoryURL()
    }
}
```

This class-file, as well as my Core-Data-Model and the following class are all in target membership of all of the mentioned targets. The Codegen of the Entities is set to `Class Definition`. So far I'm using the default implementation for the Core Data Stack:

```
class DataManager {
    /**
     * Singleton Implementation
     */
    internal static let sharedInstance:DataManager = {
        let instance = DataManager()
        return instance
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    lazy var persistentContainer: PFPersistentContainer = {
        let container = PFPersistentContainer(name: "Data")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the weird part: Accessing this data from the Today- and Message-Extension seems to work gracefully (I'm assuming the Search-Extension is working too, but so far as a developer I'm not able to test this). Trying to fetch it with the same Request from the Watch App's Extension results in an empty Array. Here is my fetch code:

```
    internal func getLimitedPOIsWithCalculatedDistance(andCurrentLocation currentLocation:CLLocation) -> Array<POI> {
        var poiArray:Array< POI > = []
        guard let context = self.backgroundContext else { return [] }
        do {
            // Initialize Fetch Request
            let request:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "POI")

            // Create Entity Description
            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "POI", in: context)

            // Configure Fetch Request
            request.entity = entityDescription

            // Configure Predicate
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(disabled == NO) AND (locationDistanceCalculated <= \(SETTINGS_MAXIMUM_FETCH_DISTANCE))")
            request.predicate = predicate
            if let result = try context.fetch(request) as? Array<POI> {
                for poi in result {
                    let poiLocation = CLLocation(latitude: poi.locationLatitude, longitude: poi.locationLongitude)
                    let distance = currentLocation.distance(from: poiLocation)
                    poi.locationDistanceTransient = Double(distance)
                }

                poiArray = result.filter({ (poi) -> Bool in
                    return poi.locationDistanceTransient > 0.0
                })

                poiArray.sort { (first, second) -> Bool in
                    return first.locationDistanceTransient < second.locationDistanceTransient
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error in WatchDataInterface.getLimitedPOIsWithCalculatedDistance(): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return poiArray
    }
```

> A bit more context for better understanding: the **POI** Entitie contains latitude and longitude of a location. When starting the app, I'm pre-calculating the distance to each point in the database from the current user's position. When the Today-Extension tries to get the nearest x (in my case 8) POIs to the current users position, fetching all 15k POIs and calculating their distance is to much memory wise. So I had to pre-calculate the distance (stored in `locationDistanceCalculated`), then fetch in a given radius (the static `SETTINGS_MAXIMUM_FETCH_DISTANCE`) and calculate a precise distance during the fetch process (stored into a transient property `locationDistanceTransient`).

In the Watch App's `ExtensionDelegate` Class a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` is implemented and the code is called, when the User's Location is updated:

```
extension ExtensionDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation{
            if let watchDataManager = self.watchDataManager {
                // getNearestPOIs() calls the getLimitedPOIsWithCalculatedDistance() function and returns only a numberOfPOIs
                self.nearbyPOIs = watchDataManager.getNearestPOIs(numberOfPOIs: 4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It was tested in Simulator and on a Device. The `context.fetch` always returns an empty array (Yes, core data contains values and yes I've tested it without the predicate). Am I missing anything new in Core Data, which I haven't considered yet or are their any limitations in WatchOS3 why this isn't working out? Does anyone has a clue? Thanks for your help.

**Update:** when using a Watch Framework target to access Core Data, like it's described [in this project](https://github.com/aalittle/CoreDataWatchKit), the fetch keeps being empty. Maybe this could be the right path, but a Watch Framework is the wrong selection. Will keep you up to date.

**Update 2:** I've already checked the [App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html) for WatchOS and the `transferFile:metadata:` [function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615667-transferfile) in the API References, but it doesn't seem to be a suitable way to send these large amounts of data to the AppleWatch.  I just can't rely on the circumstance, that the user is checking the app more often than he is traveling out of the `SETTINGS_MAXIMUM_FETCH_DISTANCE` radius and for locations with a high density of POIs this data is even more extensive.

**Update 3:** I've reimplemented the nearby Feature for POIs to fetch only in a given radius. If this solves a problem for you, check out this public [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kayoslab/90ffed97919e6413ae95df5cf86aa2f7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Watch OS3, you cannot access a `CoreData` base using App Group trick ( because the watch is supposed to work without a phone.

So you have to use `WatchConnectivity` to fetch your data

Comment: Thanks for your hint towards WatchConnectivity, this is close towards a possible solution, but not what I've intended to implement. Maybe I'll give it a try and wrap  the rest of the implementation around it. You'll get the reward.